# How to I scale my text to past 1269pt in CS6 illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, font-size, scale

I've tried the scale function and it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what else to do. Please help.

Comment: Why do you need your text to be so enormously big? If it’s because you’re making something like a billboard, the normal strategy is to make it at a fraction of the final size and then have it upscaled when printed.

Answer (score 1):

That is way too big. Work all your project in scale.

But if for some reason you still need a typo that big, you could convert it to curves and scale it up as you wish.